# Site in site apache2

Tags: php, nginx, apache2, yii2

**Hi all!**

I have old site on clear php, new functionality start writing on Yii2.

```
-- old site
   |
   -- index.php (old site)
   |
   -- yii2
      |
      -- web
         |
         -- index.php (new site)
```

I need to configure all request on

**site.ll/* -> index.php (old site)**

**site.ll/v2/* -> yii2/web/index.php (new site)**

I trying like this:
**Alias** /v2 /srv/site/yii2/web

Alias is not ported on Nginx, but I need to run this configuration on apache and on nginx.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Just using rewrites:**

```
RewriteRule v2/*?$ /srv/old_site/yii2/web/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule v2/*?(.*)?/?$ /srv/old_site/yii2/web/index.php/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule v2/*?(.*)?/?(.*)?$ /srv/old_site/yii2/web/index.php/$1/$2 [NC,L]
```